# Synonym of Incendiary

Tags: synonyms

I am looking for a synonym of `incendiary`, which means:

```
causing or having the potential to cause a fire
```

I cannot seem to find a synonym for this definition of the word, because most of the synonyms of the word relate to causing trouble or damage, but none are related to causing a fire.

Example: Incendiary weapons were used to burn down the building.

Comment: Are *pyrogenic* and *inflammable* not suitable?  I echo chasly: context is everything.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Yeah, *inflammable* isn't quite right.  Inflammable things aren't themselves the cause of their burning.  *Inflammatory*, though, means being provocative or causing tissue inflammation.

Comment: @deadrat - pyrogenic refers to heat generation, what doesn't mean that there is ignition or fire.

Comment: @Graffito No, per the *OED* fire or heat, depending the circumstance of use.  The latter for geological uses, for example.  After all, the words comes to us from the Greek word for fire, *πυρ*.  It's not ideal, since it's medical use means fever-inducing, but it's hard to know what to suggest when the OP doesn't like the most apt word.

Comment: @deadrat - in the OED sense, a pyrogenic material has been produced by heat or combustion and was not the cause of the fire. However, I was also surprised that, according to dictionaries, pyrogenic (what I understand well as a cause of fire) don't really reflect its etymology.

Answer (score 1):

Consider, [flamethrowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flamethrower).

> : throwing out flames; *a flamethrowing tank* [English
>   Wiktionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/flamethrowing)

Answer (score 0):

com·bus·ti·ble

adjective

> able to catch fire and burn easily.

"highly combustible paint thinner"

synonyms:   inflammable, flammable, incendiary, ignitable

"piles of combustible material"

Comment: I am sorry for any confusion with my question. You are correct, this answer would be incorrect according to my question.

Comment: How was his question incorrect?? @chaslyfromUK

Comment: He is saying that this answer does not fit my question, not that my question is incorrect, but that it would be if this was the answer.

Comment: If combustible means `able to catch fire and burn easily`, then it is not capable of causing fire, but rather only able to catch fire.

Comment: Your answer isn't really bad, but I would like something more related to causing fire.

Comment: If I call a certain machine combustible then that it means it can cause a fire. What are you talking about?

Comment: Combustible: `able to catch fire and burn easily`; Incendiary: `causing or having the potential to cause a fire`

Comment: Able to catch fire doesn't just mean from an outside source. It can catch fire on its own as well.

Comment: Something that is incendiary can cause something that is combustible to catch fire, but something that is combustible cannot cause fire by itself.

Comment: Of course it can.